# Netsh DHCP alternative configuration

Tags: dhcp, netsh

My first step for configure my interface in dhcp, is to use this command:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Connexion au réseau local" dhcp
```

But after, how i can configure alternative ip (APIPA) with netsh or others?

Comment: Not sure what your question is exactly, but you can use `add` instead of `set` to add IP addresses to the same Ethernet adaptor, e.g. `netsh interface ip add address "Connexion au réseau local" 10.0.0.1 255.0.0.0`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I need to add alternate configuration  (to my interface in dhcp)  with a script, like the picture: [link](http://www.pctips3000.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Provide-Alternative-IP-Address.jpg)

Comment: No, your command replace dhcp configuration by a static configuration.